# Weblogic 12c deployment error : unsupported classversion 52.0

Tags: java, weblogic, javac, ear

I'm trying to deploy an EAR file to WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.1.0 but it gives me this error:

```
weblogic.management.DeploymentException:
Error mydirectory/weblogic/LifeCycleListener : unsupported classversion 52.0
```

LifeCycleListener is a .java file. Here is the Java version I have installed on my machine, and with which i compiled the EAR file:

```
C:\Users\USER>java -version
java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode, sharing)
javac 1.8.0_11
```

why is this happening? i have the JDK up to date and everything..is there any code I can put in the java file or any solution?

Comment: What JVM version does the WebLogic Server run on?

Comment: @reto I don't know how can I find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compiled your code with Java 8, but your Weblogic server is running an older Java version.
Either compile your code using the Java version of your target server, or upgrade your server's Java engine to Java 8.